# Подскажите как такое сделать на css

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как сделать такой таб на css с минимумом html кода ?

Answer (score 2):

Тут вроде бы не высшая математика

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: darkblue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: darkblue;
  padding: 4px 14px 4px 6px;
  margin: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">далее1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">далее2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">далее3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">далее4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: одно скругление забыли, на стыке блока и линии

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг на css такое не сделаешь требуются какие то дополнительные движняки

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг хотя щас попробую на css такую штуку сделать

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг  https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/LwGbav  вот смотри - топорное решение но оно есть

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов. На эталон не претендую.

```css
.tabcl {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.tabcl > span {
  padding: 3px 9px;
  background-color: #3399CC;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.tabcl > span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #3399CC;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabcl">
  <span>Прочее</span>
</div>
```

Comment: одно скругление забыли, на стыке блока и линии

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг если только добавить еще один элемент, перекрывающий выступающий таб. изменить для примера? и вам нужен таб как статический элемент или как ul-li ?

Comment: да в принципе без разницы, я основу сетки беру на бутстрапе а потом туда подгоню это